# Swapping attribute of two instances

Tags: python, class, oop, attributes, instance

So I am trying to make a turn-based card game, and one of the cards, when played , can swap the hand of the "caster" and the "castee" (not sure if that's even a word). I created a `Player` class, and instances `Jim`, `Pam`, `Dwight` and `Michael`. Whenever that card is played I have to swap the `hand` attribute between two players.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, hand=[]):
        self.name = name
        self.hand = [self.draw_card() for n in range(0, 2)]
```

I've tried creating a method which takes the "castee", which is the `self` in this case, and swaps hand with the caster, but it doesn't work. Here `caster` is the name of the other instance, e.g. it could be `Michael.hand` instead of `caster.hand`:

```
def hand_swap(self):
    self.hand, caster.hand = caster.hand, self.hand
```

I've also tried the following with no luck:

```
def hand_swap(self):
    myhand = self.hand.copy()
    casterhand = caster.hand.copy()
    setattr(caster, "hand", myhand)
    setattr(self, "hand", casterhand)
```

After every loop, players and their hands are printed in a dictionary. The code doesn't throw up any errors, but no hand has been swapped and everything remains the same.

Is there something wrong with my code or is it not so straightforward when it comes to having one instance change another instance's attributes?

edit1: what "caster" is
edit2: how I check that it fails

Comment: Where is `caster` defined? Should that be an argument to `hand_swap()` ?

Comment: I think both methods should work. Why do you say they don't?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `hand` argument to `__init__()`? You never use it. And watch out for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: @sj95126 editted, thanks

Comment: @Barmar editted, thanks

Comment: If the hands are in a dictionary, swapping the variables won't affect the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `caster` to `hand_swap()` you will achieve your goal.

```
def hand_swap(self, caster):
    self.hand, caster.hand = caster.hand, self.hand
```

Then to swap hands

```
pam.hand_swap(michael)
```